# Remove duplicate values from a string in java

Tags: java, string, duplicates

Can anyone please let me know how to remove duplicate values from

```
String s="Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai";
```

and output should be like

```
String s="Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-";
```

using Java..

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sure you want the `"-"` at the end of the result?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This does it in one line:

```
public String deDup(String s) {
    return new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("-"))).toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "").replace(", ", "-");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(deDup("Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai"));
}
```

Output:

```
Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork
```

Notice that the order is preserved :)

Key points are:

- `split("-")` gives us the different values as an array
- `Arrays.asList()` turns the array into a List
- `LinkedHashSet` preserves uniqueness *and* insertion order - it does all the work of giving us the unique values, which are passed via the constructor
- the `toString()` of a List is `[element1, element2, ...]`
- the final `replace` commands remove the "punctuation" from the `toString()`

This solution requires the values to not contain the character sequence `", "` - a reasonable requirement for such terse code.

#### Java 8 Update!

Of course it's 1 line:

```
public String deDup(String s) {
    return Arrays.stream(s.split("-")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining("-"));
}
```

#### Regex update!

If you don't care about preserving order (ie it's OK to delete the *first* occurrence of a duplicate):

```
public String deDup(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(\\b\\w+\\b)-(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "");
}
```

Comment: Cutting of the brackets would I do using substring(), and do it on two lines instead.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux you could break this up into many lines, but this answer is also a demonstration of how it can be done in just one line.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static String removeDuplicates(String txt, String splitterRegex)
{
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] splitted = txt.split(splitterRegex);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length; ++i)
    {
        if (!values.contains(splitted[i]))
        {
            values.add(splitted[i]);
            sb.append('-');
            sb.append(splitted[i]);
        }
    }
    return sb.substring(1);

}
```

Usage:

```
String s = "Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai";
s = removeDuplicates(s, "\\-");
System.out.println(s);
```

Prints:

```
Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork
```

Answer (score 2):

You could add your strings to a HashSet.

1. Split the strings on a "-".
2. Store the individual words in Array. i.e arr[]

Sinppet :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    for(int i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(set.contains(arr[i])){
        System.out.println("Duplicate string found at index " + i);
      } else {
        set.add(arr[i]);
      }
```

Comment: Or a LinkedHashSet to keep the original order

Comment: C'mon are you for real?  You're checking to see if the String is already in the Set.  But the whole point of a Set is that it doesn't contain duplicates.  That's redundant code!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just the idea:

1. parse the string and split the tokens using separator "-"
2. load the tokens into a `Collection`
3. iterate the `Collection` and erase duplicates
4. use the result `Collection` to build the new string

The most tricky part should be 3, but not impossible. If you use a `Set`, you can skip this step.

**EDIT** maybe you can substitute 2&3 with a presence check before adding the element

Answer (score 1):

Create array of string by spliting by `-` and then create a hashSet from it.

```
String s="Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai"; 
String[] strArr = s.split("-");
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strArr));
```

If you want back it as string array then do following:

```
String[] result = new String[set.size()];
set.toArray(result);
```

Here is a sample code to do this:

```
String s="Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai"; 
String[] strArr = s.split("-");
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(strArr));
String[] result = new String[set.size()];
set.toArray(result);
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    String string = result[i];
    if(i==result.length-1)
        res.append(string);
    else
        res.append(string).append("-");
}
System.out.println(res.toString());
```

Output:-

```
Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static String RemoveDuplicateCharInString(String s){
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if((s.substring(i+1)).indexOf(s.charAt(i))!=-1){
            s=s.substring(0,i+1)+(s.substring(i+1)).replaceAll(""+s.charAt(i),"");
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: You should say a few words about your code solution and how it answers the OPs question so that they can understand it, rather than just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

```
wordsArray = s.split("-");
List<String> wordsList = new Arrays.asList(wordsArray);
Set<String>  wordsSet  = new LinkedHashSet<String>(wordsList);

String[] noDuplicates = new String[wordsSet.size()];
wordsSet.toArray(noDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer this which is simpler than all of the above.

```
public void removeDuplicates() {
  String myString = "Bangalore-Chennai-NewYork-Bangalore-Chennai";

  String[] array = myString.split("-");

  Set<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));

  String newString = StringUtils.join(hashSet, "-");        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str="Bangalore-Chennai-Newyork-Bangalore-Chennai";
    String output="";
    String [] arr=str.split("-");

    LinkedHashSet<String> lhs=new LinkedHashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        lhs.add(arr[i]);
    }
    for(String s:lhs){
        output=output+s+"-";
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: It'd be good to explain what the solution would be, rather than just pasting the code of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the game, but I would simply use a HashMap. It's easy to understand and has quick lookups on the keys, might not be the best way but it's still a good answer IMO. I use it all the time when I need to format quick and dirty:

```
                    String reason = "Word1 , Word2 , Word3";
                    HashMap<String,String> temp_hash = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    StringBuilder reason_fixed = new StringBuilder();
                    //in:
                    for(String word : reason.split(",")){
                        temp_hash.put(word,word);
                    }
                    //out:
                    for(String words_fixed : temp_hash.keySet()){
                        reason_fixed.append(words_fixed + " , ");
                    }
                    //print:
                    System.out.println(reason_fixed.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RemDuplicateWordFromString {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Hello India Hello India Hello India Hello India";
    countWords(s1);
}
public static void countWords(String s1) {
    String[] s2 = s1.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s2.length; j++) {
            if (s2[i].equals(s2[j])) {
                if (i != j) {
                    s2[i] = "";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s2.length; i++) {
        if (s2[i] != "") {
            System.out.print(s2[i] + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder builderWord = new StringBuilder(word);
for(int index=0; index < builderWord.length(); index++) {
    for(int reverseIndex=builderWord.length()-1; reverseIndex > index;reverseIndex--) {
        if (builderWord.charAt(reverseIndex) == builderWord.charAt(index)) {
            builderWord.deleteCharAt(reverseIndex);
        }
    }
}
return builderWord.toString();
```

Comment: Please don't just post code blocks without context - include an explanation as well

Answer (score 0):

Java8

Make the string into stream of array, split the string, make it sequential, collect the elements into a set, that's all.  You can include the whole line inside `System.out.prinln()` to print the set of strings.

```
Arrays.stream(s.split("-")).sequential().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class SplitString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String st = new String("New Delhi-Chennai-New York-Bangalore-Chennai-New Delhi-Chennai-New York");
        StringBuffer stb = new StringBuffer();

        HashSet<String> hashset = new HashSet<String>();
        for (String a : st.split("-"))
            hashset.add(a);

        Object[] str = (Object[]) hashset.toArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            stb.append(str[i]);

            if (i < str.length - 1)
                stb.append("-");

        }

        System.out.println(stb);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.*;

public class RemoveDuplicateWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Hai hello Hai how hello are how you";
        removeDupWord(str);
    }

    public static void removeDupWord(String input) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(input.split(" "));
        LinkedHashSet<String> lhs = new LinkedHashSet<String>(list);
        for(String s : lhs) {
            System.out.print(s+" ");
        }                   
    }
}
```