# Remove duplicate set of strings in a hyphen separated big string

Tags: java, split, duplicates

I'm developing in Java, I have the following string:

```
String duplicates = "Smith, John - Smith, John - Smith, John – Wilson, Peter";
```

I need to get a new string with no duplicate names.

```
unique = "Smith, John – Wilson, Peter";
```

I thought I could use

```
String unique[] = duplicates.split("-");
```

Problem with splitting hyphens with commas is that now I have all commas

```
Smith, John, Smith, John, Smith, John, Wilson, Peter
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you need to split on a comma rather that dash?

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean however, is there a way to work around with hyphens?

Comment: Aren't the names the full "Smith, John"? in which case you are getting the right names by doing split('-') ?

Comment: For example, the following will print the unique names:

`String str = "Smith, John - Smith, John - Smith, John - Wilson, Peter";`
`Arrays.stream(str.split("-")).map(s->s.trim()).distinct().forEach(System.out::println);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I eliminate duplicate words from String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770863/how-can-i-eliminate-duplicate-words-from-string-in-java)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate values from a string in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6790689/remove-duplicate-values-from-a-string-in-java)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `distinct()` operation of stream

```
Arrays.stream(duplicates.split("\\s+(-|–|‒|–|—|―)+\\s+")) // split by different types of dashes surrounded by whitespaces
      .distinct()        // get rid of duplicates
      .collect(Collectors.toList())
      .forEach(System.out::println); // print each entry
```

Output:

```
Smith, John
Wilson, Peter
```

Or use `Collectors.joining` to get a string without duplicates:

```
String duplicates = "Smith, John -- Smith, John - Smith, John – Wilson, Peter ‒ Yves Saint-Laurent ― George Henry Lane-Fox Pitt-Rivers";

String noDuplicates = Arrays.stream(duplicates.split("\\s+(-|–|‒|–|—|―)+\\s+"))
                            .distinct()
                            .collect(Collectors.joining(" – "));
System.out.println(noDuplicates);
```

prints:

```
Smith, John – Wilson, Peter – Yves Saint-Laurent – George Henry Lane-Fox Pitt-Rivers
```

I updated the detection of the names which can contain single hyphens to handle "double-barrelled" names which are quite popular, and added types of [dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)

Comment: I do have one quick question.... why using the      ("-|–")   ?

Comment: in case your input string contains different types of dashes/hyphens - as in your input string there are at least two types: `"-"` and `"–"`.  You may check updated input string in my example.

Comment: Do I close it? Not sure how

Comment: Meaning?  You can accept my answer - put a green tick

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Java, one last question, what is  ".collect(Collectors.joining(" – "));"  doing?    is it joining again with another delimiter after you've removed the original delimiter?

Comment: Yes, according to your requirement: _I need to get a new string with no duplicate names `unique = "Smith, John – Wilson, Peter";`_